# A nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop. Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as an iterator

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

**I have to get data from Firebase Database and through the key "keys" take all the data and insert them in "postsList". To do this I used the for-in loop. The latter throws me an error.**

*The error is: "A nullable expression can't be used as an iterator in a for-in loop. Try checking that the value isn't 'null' before using it as an iterator."*

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<Posts> postsList = [];


  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();


    DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");

    postsRef.once().then((snap)
        {

      var keys = snap.snapshot.key;
      var values = snap.snapshot.value;

      postsList.clear();

      for (var individual in keys) {
        Posts posts = Posts(
          values[individual]['url'],
          values[individual]['descrizione'],
          values[individual]['data'],
          values[individual]['ora'],
        );
        postsList.add(posts);
      }


      setState(()
      {
       print('Length : $postsList.length');
      });

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

Add `!` behind keys, for example : `for(key in keys!`

```
  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();


    DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");

    postsRef.once().then((snap)
        {

      var keys = snap.snapshot.key;
      var values = snap.snapshot.value;

      postsList.clear();

      for (var individual in keys!) {
        Posts posts = Posts(
          values[individual]['url'],
          values[individual]['descrizione'],
          values[individual]['data'],
          values[individual]['ora'],
        );
        postsList.add(posts);
      }


      setState(()
      {
       print('Length : $postsList.length');
      });

    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message should come with a link to this documentation page on [unchecked use of a nullable value](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#unchecked_use_of_nullable_value). As the error says, the `keys` variable you use in `for (var individual in keys) {` can be null, which isn't allowed. You should either check if it's null, or assert that it isn't null:

```
if (keys != null) {
  for (var individual in keys) {
    Posts posts = Posts(
      values[individual]['url'],
      values[individual]['descrizione'],
      values[individual]['data'],
      values[individual]['ora'],
    );
    postsList.add(posts);
  }
}
```

---

The above fixes the syntax/compiler problem, but there may well be other problems in your code as I suspect that your `keys` variable will be a single string with the value `Posts`. If that's the case, consider looping over `values` instead, with the same null check as above.

---

Map<String,int>.from(event.snapshot.value)

map.forEach((k, v) => print("Key : $k, Value : $v"));

```
DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");

postsRef.once().then((snap) {
  //  Get a map of the top-level post keys and post values
  var map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snap.snapshot.value);

  postsList.clear();

  //  Loop over the post keys and post values
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    //  Get the values for this post as another map
    var values = Map<String, dynamic>.from(map);
    Posts posts = Posts(
      values['url'],
      values['descrizione'],
      values['data'],
      values['ora'],
    );
    postsList.add(posts);
  });

  setState(() {
    print('Length : $postsList.length');
  });
});
```

Comment: in fact now the error has become: "The type 'String' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable. " how can i proceed?

Comment: Did you read the second half of my answer and apply that?

Comment: yes, i have an error about "values" in the for loop: "The type 'Object' used in the 'for' loop must implement Iterable"

Comment: So that's again a different error. What type do you expect `values` to be? And did you try casting it to that type?

Comment: `values` is of type object, it's done like this: -MsjPJX5n5eOQiQKvMIR: {descrizione: mama, data: Jan 6, 2022, url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/blogap..[], ora: Thursday, 01:42 PM},

Comment: I added a longer example of how to process this structure. which as far as I can see requires two nested maps.

Comment: I followed your example, now I have an error on the "snap.snapshot.value" parameter in the following line "var map = Map <String, dynamic> .from (snap.snapshot.value);". The error is "The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map <dynamic, dynamic>'. "

Comment: Did you search for that error message yet? What is your take on what's causing this latest problem, and the approach we can take to fix it?